# Live video recording wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, streaming, recording

I need to create live video recording: during video recording the video stream translates on server without saving video on device. But i can't find a way to implement this. Is there a way to create such video recording on windows phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone Camera API allows you to access the raw video stream. Start by reading tutorials on this API such as the one below:

[Windows Phone 7.5 - Manipulating camera stream](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.5-Manipulating-camera-stream.aspx)